# How to print string in view from controller method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, methods, controller, concatenation

I have a database with a column for each day of the week containing business hours in it. Any day that the business is closed has no data in the table for that column.

My goal is to read this data out by the day and print something like the following in my view:

```
Monday: 8am - 5pm
Tuesday: 8am - 5pm
Friday: 8am - pm
```

skipping the days that the business is not open. In my controller I have my index method:

```
    def index
        @locations = Location.all
    end
```

along with a different method that accepts a location:

```
    def gettimes(location)
    @campus = Location.where(:name => 'Tennille')
        sunday = @campus.sunday
        monday = @campus.monday
        tuesday = @campus.tuesday
        wednesday = @campus.wednesday
        thursday = @campus.thursday
        friday = @campus.friday
        saturday = @campus.saturday

        if @campus.sunday.empty
            @hours += "Sunday: #{sunday}<br />"
        end
        if @campus.monday.empty
            @hours +=  "Monday: #{monday}<br />"
        end
        if @campus.tuesday.empty
            @hours +=  "Tuesday: #{tuesday}<br />"
        end
        if @campus.wednesday.empty
            @hours +=  "Wednesday: #{wednesday}<br />"
        end
        if @campus.thursday.empty
            @hours +=  "Thursday: #{thursday}<br />"
        end
        if @campus.friday.empty
            @hours +=  "Friday: #{friday}<br />"
        end
        if @campus.saturday.empty
            @hours +=  "Saturday: #{saturday}<br />"
        end

        puts @hours
    end
```

I am at a complete loss on how to call this method, let alone print the result in the view.

My view runs through the database entries like so:

```
    <% @locations.each do |location| %>
    <%= location.etc %>
```

I am not even sure if I'm doing the string concatenation correctly so any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a method in the ApplicationHelper.rb

```
def show_time_board(location)
  board = ""
  ["sunday", "monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday", "saturday"].each do |day_of_the_week|
    board += "#{day_of_the_week.capitalize}: #{location.send(day_of_the_week)}<br />" if location.send(day_of_the_week).present?
  end
  board
end
```

And in the view

```
<% @locations.each do |location| %>
  <%= show_time_board(location).html_safe %>
<% end %>
```

And you should be using ul and li as html tags and not